# How to pass data from Activity to Fragment using bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am completely new to Android and I have to submit this app to end my college degree, but I am having this problem where my fragment crashes my entire app.

To explain what I have done up until now is, I have a LoginActivity where I sent the userId through the Intent and have the id of the current user on my DashboardActivity (and I can display it), but in the DashboardActivity I have a bottom navigation bar that navigates to my FormFragment and my DataFragment.

Right now, want I would love to pass the userId value of the current user from the DashboardActivity to my DataFragment, so that I can display dynamically the user data according to the userId.

So with it, I found that the best option is to use bundle, but I don't now why (because I am completely new to this) my app crashes every time I switch from my FormFragment to my DataFragment.

Can you help me? I am desperate xD

This is my DashboardActivity code:

```
public class PainelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button buttonLogout;
    private TextView textViewId;
    private Object DashboardFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_painel);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);

        // gets the id from the Intent
        Intent get = getIntent();
        String userId = get.getStringExtra(LoginActivity.EXTRA_ID);

        // Send the id to the Fragments
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("userId", userId);
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment).commit();

        // see the id on the screen
        textViewId = findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
        textViewId.setText(userId);

        // logout
        buttonLogout = findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
        buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openMainActivity();
            }
        });
    }
    public void openMainActivity() {
        Intent HomePage = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(HomePage);

        Toast.makeText(PainelActivity.this, "Terminou a sua sessão.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

And this is my DataFragment code:

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {
    INodeJS myAPI;
    private TextView textViewResult;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

        //Init API
        Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
        myAPI = retrofit.create(INodeJS.class);
        textViewResult = root.findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);

        // gets the id from the activity
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            String userId = getArguments().getString("userId");
            int uid = Integer.parseInt(userId);

            Call<List<DataResult>> call = myAPI.executeGetData(uid);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DataResult>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<DataResult>> call, Response<List<DataResult>> response) {
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        List<DataResult> DATA = response.body();

                        for (DataResult data: DATA) {
                            String content = "";
                            content += "Data: " +data.getDta() + "\n";
                            content += "Hora: " +data.getHora() + "\n";
                            content += "Glicémia: " +data.getIndiceGlicemia() + "\n";
                            content += "Insulina: " +data.getInsulina() + "\n";
                            content += "Medicação: " +data.getMedicacao() + "\n\n";

                            textViewResult.append(content);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<DataResult>> call, Throwable t) {
                    textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }

        return root;
    }
}
```

Thank you and have a nice day!

(I just edited my code and updated my question, right now, my app doesn't crash but I don't see the data.)

Comment: Could you show logcat when your app crash?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/pbwKU6J Here is a screenshot of my Logcat

Comment: I have not seen the code that setArgument for `DashboardFragment`.

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While creating bundle:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("userId", userId);
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder_id, dataFragment, "anyTagName").commit();
```

The To get the data in your fragment:

```
if (getArguments != null) {
    String userId = getArguments().getString("userId");
}
```

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder_id, dataFragment, "anyTagName").commit();

what it does exactly?

Comment: It return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated with this activity.

Comment: replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder_id  Should this be my Activity then?

Comment: .replace(R.id.DashboardActivity, DashboardFragment, "passData").commit();  Should it be like this?

Comment: It should be the placeholder's id where you want the fragment. Placeholder in the xml layout of your activity.

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, (Fragment) DashboardFragment, "passData").commit();   I have it like this now, is it right? What's the tag for? Thank you so much for you patience explaining me this!

Comment: I have to see your current activity's xml layout to say if it's right. Tag is like an Id that you have to explicitly provide when you want to use support-based Fragments from activity. Add any unique tag in string.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a new fragment you have an auto-generated function called `newInstance`.

So what you need to do is:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("ARG_NAME", param1);
        args.putString("OTHER_ARG_NAME", param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
}
```

Then, in your activity:

```
String str1 = "foo";
String str2 = "bar";
MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance(str1, str2);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                 .beginTransaction()
                                 .replace(R.id.nameOfActivityLayout, myFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null); // Add this line if you want to add the fragment to the back-stack
transaction.commit();
```

And back to your fragment, in your `onCreate` method :

```
String str1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            str1 = getArguments().getString("ARG_NAME");
        }
    }
```

The variable `str1` will now have the value `"foo"` and you're free to use it in your fragment. Of course you can put other types in the bundle, like integers, booleans, arrays etc.

Comment: Is it really necessary to create a new instance? Because all I want is to pass the data (userId) to my existent fragments, I just want them to have access. This is way complicated than I thought geez xD

Comment: Well I also thought it was complicated initially but it actually really isn't. Creating a new instance replaces your `Fragment fragment = new Fragment();`, it's just another way of creating an instance of that fragment, which supports passing arguments into it in an easy and convenient manner.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the jetpack navigation component, so its easier than before.
You just have to pass the bundle to the navigation controller

Do:

navController.setGraph(R.navigation.graph, YOUR_BUNDLE);

then in your start fragment:
Bundle b = getArguement();
String id = b.Get string("I'd");

Comment: So, in my setGraph what arguments should I pass? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Pass String argument or int. Depends on ur need. Like: Bundle b = new Bundle();  b.setString("id", id);